# Getting character count in string

Tags: c#, validation, count

I have a string that I am trying to get the count of characters in. I have a variable named `myNumber` that contains a phone number, I want to make sure the character length is equal to 9 for a valid US phone number. Here is my code:

```
string myNumber = myTable.Rows[i][myRealNumber].ToString().Replace("-", "");
```

Then I am trying to use `Count` to get character count:

```
myNumber.Count
```

But it doesn't like that... At all

Any advice?

Comment: `myNumber.`, *wait for half a second*, look at the available method/property names.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = "some string".Count(); // Extension method
int length = "some string".Length; // Property
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right phone number validation is not count of number digits but using the regular expression

```
\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b
```

for US number matching